# unit testing <input type="file " accet="image/*"/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, filereader, enzyme

how to unit test the following code

```
<input type="file " accet="image/*"/>
```

using jasmine and  enzyme

i have refereed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702911/how-can-i-test-a-change-handler-for-a-file-type-input-in-react-using-jest-enzyme) 
but here they have a plain text file, i want to test image file
how to test image file,instead of simple text file as in the above link

in The above referenced link they created a text file, if anyone has a solution how create a image file using blob api then my problem would be solved

Comment: accet?? what is that?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256755/6429700

Comment: @LelioFaieta it is accept

Comment: @Nirali what is new File([blob], "filename") is doing ? i think it just creating a empty file with "filename "

Comment: @Nirali thanks , you saved my day